# Как поменять порядок отображения блоков?

Tags: html, css

Менять код HTML нельзя (у меня адаптивная верстка, может кто знает, как менять HTML код при разных расширениях, то буду очень довольный, если подскажите). Попробую показать, что я хочу. Есть код:

```
<div class="col">...</div> 
<div class="col">...</div> 
<div class="col">...</div> 
<div class="col">...</div> 
<div class="col five">...</div>
```

Нужно, чтобы последний блок занимал 100% ширины и был сверху, остальные 4 блока были под ним и были по 25% каждый. Пока подумаю на абсолютом или :before. Буду рад отдельным советам. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[А если так попробовать?](http://jsfiddle.net/CbF9B/13/)

Comment: Он похож по сути на способ который предложил ReklatsMasters.Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.Тоже вариант.

Comment: Похож, но он элегантнее и работает в IE8.

Comment: В ie7 тоже работает, но вот только width придется ставить не 25 а 24 px

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/CbF9B/). Не работает в IE8 и менее.

(.wrapper - родитель для всего этого блока колонок)

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;        
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;   
}

.col {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50px;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
    left: 25%;
}

.col:nth-child(3) {
    left: 50%;
}

.col:nth-child(4) {
    left: 75%;
}

.five {
    top: 0; 
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0 !important;
}
​
```

Comment: Очень интересный способ через table-row.Делов том что я хочу поддерживать ие7-8.Но суть мне второго способа ясна.Буду наверное навешивать классы и делать через абсолют.Спасибо.

Comment: [HowTo](http://tanalin.com/articles/css-block-order/) Тут подробнее. Просто вы задали критерий, чтобы не менять разметку.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того что в этих колонках. Фикс высота или нет и т.д.

Comment: А есть только решения для фиксир.?Предложи пожалуйста.